# AWS DMS Task Migration Mapping Rules - Add-Column using metadata

Tags: amazon-web-services, metadata, database-replication, cdc, aws-dms

I need to create a new column for each record that DMS processes, right now I have the following mapping rule:

```json
{
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "2",
      "rule-target": "column",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "my_schema",
        "table-name": "%"
      },
      "rule-action": "add-column",
      "value": "_my_column",
      "expression": "'test_val_'||$AR_M_SOURCE_SCHEMA||'.'||$AR_M_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME",
      "data-type": {
        "type": "string",
        "length": 200
      }
    }
```

and it validates correctly and runs a full load and CDC without error. The problem is that the resulting column value for `_my_column` looks like `test_val_.`

I followed the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Expressions.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Expressions-Metadata) and it seems to very clearly indicate that these values should *not* be empty strings.

> You can add the metadata information to the target table by using the expressions following:

> $AR_M_SOURCE_SCHEMA – The name of the source schema.
> $AR_M_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME – The name of the source table.
> $AR_M_SOURCE_COLUMN_NAME – The name of a column in the source table.
> $AR_M_SOURCE_COLUMN_DATATYPE – The data type of a column in the source table.

I can't find any other resource from AWS that indicates how I would get the source schema and table values for the mapping. I can see when the data is inserted into the target database that there is metadata and it does include the schema & table names, so the information exists at the time the record is written.

I know that I can include the schema in the literal string since I am already setting it somewhere else in the mapping, but I would need to add this to every table in the schema, so I need that value from the metadata while it is processing.

I must be missing something obvious, does anyone know what the issue here is?

Answer (score 1):

found the issue. I don't know why and there is nothing in the documentation that indicates this (that I could find) but referencing *two* metadata variables seems to break it and have all metadata variables return an empty string value.

```json
      "expression": "'test_val_myschema'.'||$AR_M_SOURCE_TABLE_NAME",
```

works. Hopefully this answer can help someone else who gets stuck here